# Is there an OAuth flow that doesn't require a client_id?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, botframework

I have created a Microsoft Teams bot built using a Golang port of the Bot Framework. It is a multi tenant bot which lives in my infrastructure.

It is easy to add the bot as a "Teams Application" by selecting it from the marketplace (for free), however, to function correctly it needs additional Microsoft Graph permissions. Specifically read the title of a MS Teams Channel / Group Chat.

This seems to be a challenge for users as almost no one - even those 'in IT' seem able to correctly add the permissions required, even with documentation.

I've been helping them personally but it's not a commercial product so not viable in the long term.

I would like to find an OAuth2 flow which would allow a privileged user to authenticate with **their** Azure tentant and grant the necessary privileges for my application to do it's thing. Or, alternatively create the client registration in advance of installing the bot.

Every OAuth2 flow requires me to have (or know) my client_id before making the request. Given it's in the users Tenant, I don't have access to it; the users can authenticate against their Azure AD tenant though, so they must receive a bearer token which would allow them access to create or update permissions on an Azure Application.

Comment: Have you checked if _multi-tenant_ apps do what you need? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps They are typically used for apps that an admin installs for their tenant.

Answer (score 0):

There is chance to use the OAuth 2.0 client credentials. This grant is specified in RFC 6749. This grant is to access the web hosted resources. This resource will directly identify the application based on the identity of the application. In server-to-server communication we can use OAuth 2.0. This can be referred as "Service accounts" or "Daemons".

[Microsoft identity platform and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)